# Conditional argument types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, conditional-statements

I made a simplified example of my problem. `'ZERO'` as an argument is only possible, if `T` can be a number. But the TypeScript compiler gives me an error.

```
class Foo<T> {
    constructor(public value: null | T) {}

    unset(how: number extends T ? 'NULL' | 'ZERO' : 'NULL'): void {
        switch (how) {
            case 'NULL':
                this.value = null;
                break;
            case 'ZERO':
                this.value = 0; // Error! But why?
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

However outside of the class the code is working.

```
const foo1 = new Foo(42);
foo1.unset('NULL');
foo1.unset('ZERO');

const foo2 = new Foo('a');
foo2.unset('NULL');
foo2.unset('ZERO'); // Error! Alright!
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVAfNA3gKGn6w8AdhAC4BOArsKfOQBQAOlARiAJbDQBuYIlAUwBc0IpRAhoAH2goAlFgC%202XPkokBpegAt4AdxFiAtiwHloAgB6kBRACYwU0APzQA5ADkAqgBkfb6XcALQBRACUAeQCRT19-ORFueHY7LFV8fAg9dlJgbWgdfQUcDNL8YEgBd28-NyF0ssbSbXYIADpefiqAXlFxEABuBsbSlnIBMABrIZGMiogqt1DIuuHZvGbWjr5BaF6ABgHoAHpj6BDycjoAQmgAIUpSaD1tAE9nNfWxienP6GUMsplNhCCQngAzRAARj2ogEejgiHoABYAExyIaQ%20BQtrqBZaWK1DHYLE4vGaehLcJRYkg4hkaBY1GwojwxHwSlgNzEpm4jQEmrxTGIVF8-GU5Y0o6nc6XG7QACCIHI7AA5tpSNcgA)

Comment: See [this Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mZ4l1w) for an explanation why the error is justified.

Comment: Sorry. I changed my example to `number extends T`.

Comment: Maybe TypeScript doesn't support narrowing in your specific case. You might want to open an issue on the [official repository](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript)